# What programming language has datetime as primitive type (or class) (if any)?

Tags: datetime

I'm finding too difficult to work with dates in PHP, so for next project I will use other language.

I'm looking for one language that easily (preferrably out-of-the-box) support datetime, so: What programming language has datetime as primitive type (or class)?

Note: I'm not looking for recommendation of any particular language, maybe a list of languages that use datetime as **primitive type**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are primitive

- [VB.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711900(v=vs.71).aspx)

None of these are primitive, but all popular languages have DateTime classes. If one isn't to your liking, look to GitHub for community driven DateTime projects for your language of choice.

- [.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)
- [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
- [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Date.html)

Answer (score 0):

Python has a DateTime object. You can read it's documentation at https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: Is this considered "primitive"? like integer, float, str in python?

Comment: No, but why does that matter?